# GMOCK set function input and output parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, googlemock

I have a GMOCK method like below:

```
MOCK_METHOD2(FnCall, bool(const Message* request, Message*& reply));
```

I have the below test code to set the values:

```
const Message* message = new  MockMesage(9);
Message* reply = new MockMesage();

EXPECT_CALL(mMock, FnCall(::testing::_, ::testing::_)).WillOnce(::testing::SetArgReferee<0>(message));

But I get compilation errors:

C:/work/googletest/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-more-actions.h:192:3: error: static assertion failed: SetArgReferee_must_be_used_with_a_reference_argument
   GTEST_COMPILE_ASSERT_(internal::is_reference<argk_type>::value,
   ^
C:/work/googletest/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-more-actions.h:194:27: error: assignment of read-only location 'std::get<0ull, {const Message*, Message*&}>((* & args))'
   ::testing::get<k>(args) = value;
error: no matching function for call to 'SetArgReferee(Message*&)'
```

How can we set mocked function arguments whose types are pointer and reference to a pointer ?

Comment: You seem to have a serious misconception how to use mock classes in unit tests, respectively what to test with them.

Comment: I agree and I am learning by example - but can you please state the places where I have misconception - it will help me to correct myself

Comment: For starters: I'm wondering what you try to achieve as test result, when calling a mock method with mock objects?

Comment: Given for a class I would mock all its dependencies and let mocked methods to return various expected / unexpected values and test my concerned class methods / code. So if I want to test Class A which has dependencies on Class B & C - I would mock methods of class B and C and test class A such that the mocked methods of B & C will return mocked or different values. Please correct mu approach